# How to pass image from android java to JNI to filter the image using opencv and return back to android java?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I want to pass image from java to JNI and  doing some filter and other operations  and send it back to java and display it in the screen. Here is the code i tried.

The java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    static {
        try

        {
    System.loadLibrary("MyLib");
    System.loadLibrary("Opencv_java3");
        }
        catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            System.err.println("unable to load the opencv   library"+e.toString());
        }
}
public native void imageFromJNI(long inputImage,long outputImage);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  final ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_id);

final Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.read);//reading the image from drawable
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);// display the decoded image 
  final Mat inputImage=new Mat();//The input image to be sent
     Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,inputImage); //change the bitmap to mat to pass the image as argument
     final Mat outputImage=new Mat();//The result image to be returned
    final Button blurButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.blurButton_id);//Blur button to blur the displayed image when pressed
     blurButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
   int[] colors={0};
              Bitmap outputImageBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(colors,inputImage.cols(),inputImage.rows(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);// I think this creates a bitmap equals to inputImage height and width and RGB channels.
             imageFromJNI(inputImage.getNativeObjAddr(),outputImage.getNativeObjAddr());//call to native method
             Utils.matToBitmap(outputImage,outputImageBitmap);//the outputImage is changed into Bitmap in order to be displayed in the image view
             imageView.setImageBitmap(outputImageBitmap);
             blurButton.setEnabled(false);

         }
     });
}
```

}

The c++ code

```
JNIEXPORT void  JNICALL
Java_com_example_the_opencvc_MainActivity_imageFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, 
jobject ZObject,jlong inputImage,jlong outputImage) {
Mat &mat = *(Mat *) inputImage;
Mat &outputMat=*(Mat *)outputImage;
Mat mat_gray;
GaussianBlur(mat,mat,Size(3,3),0,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
cvtColor(mat,mat_gray,CV_BGRA2GRAY);
Mat mat_gradientX,mat_gradientY;
Mat mat_gradientX_abs,mat_gradientY_abs;
//apply sobel derivative

Sobel(mat_gray,mat_gradientX,-1,1,0,3,1,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
convertScaleAbs(mat_gradientX,mat_gradientX_abs);
//gradient y
Sobel(mat_gray,mat_gradientY,-1,0,1,3,1,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
convertScaleAbs(mat_gradientY,mat_gradientX_abs);
//total gradient
addWeighted(mat_gradientX_abs, 0.5 , mat_gradientY_abs , 0.5 , 0 ,
outputMat);
}
```

When i run the app the decoded image is displayed but when i press the blur button Unfortunately your app stopped error show up there is no specific cause to this error in logcat that says your app stopped working because of this.So guys am doing it wrong if so how can i pass image from android java to JNI and return it back and display the result image or point me out my error in the above code.
Thanks!

Ok here is the logcat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfUXa.png)

[image]

Comment: you need to add your log cat, then only we can investigate further.

Comment: @UMESH0492 i added the logcat.

Comment: Logcat doesn't show up anything, I would recommend you to put try catch on the code in onclick listener  and catch and print the exception. Also you are must do the encoding decoding of image in background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem it wasn't the code problem i was using opencv in java and c++.To use opencv in c++ i have Android.mk and Application.mk files and to use java i was using  [Application Development with Static Initialization](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html).Here is the problem i didn't copy the libs folder in opencv-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs folder to my app\src\main directory.